# Gaussian mixture distribution confusion

Tags: machine-learning, normal-distribution, algorithms, gaussian-mixture-distribution

Have some confusion on Gaussian mixture distribution model (reference is from the book of [Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning](http://amzn.to/2fwWIjI)). My confusion is how below formula works?

$\sum_kz_k=1$

My thought is, $z_1$ could be $0$ or $1$, $z_2$ could be $0$ or $1$, ... $z_K$ could be $0$ or $1$, how could sum of them (them I mean $z_1$, $z_2$, ..., $z_K$) to be 1?

[image]

Comment: $z_k$ is a binary component of a $K$ dimensional vector, $z$. The purpose of $z$ is to indicate which one of the $K$ populations a particular observation comes from. Under the model, an observational element must belong to one and only one of the $K$ populations. Hence the summation to 1.

Comment: Imo is correct but to complete the argument the probability that zk is 1 is the proportion that corresponds to that specific normal distribution in the mixture.

Comment: Thanks Michael, wondering what is the $z_k$ looks like, is it looks like a vector like this $(0,0,0,...1,0,0)$? Or $z_k$ is a scalar (value is either 0 or 1)?

Comment: Thanks @lmo, vote up, Confused by what do you mean "binary component" and wondering what is the $z_k$ looks like, is it looks like a vector like this $(0,0,0,...1,0,0)$? Or $z_k$ is a scalar (value is either 0 or 1)?

Comment: BTW, @lmo, is "binary component" official mathematical term? I searched wikipedia but cannot find it out. Do you mean unit vector instead?

Comment: "binary component" means that it is binary, either 0 or 1, and that it is one element in the vector. It is more or less a combination of two math terms, but probably with a computer science influence. To emphasize, let's say $z = (0, 1, 0, 0, 0)$. Then $z_1=0$,  $z_2=1$, and $z_k=0$ for $k \in \{1, 3, 4, 5 \}$.

Comment: @lmo, thanks and it is much clear now. Just to confirm my understanding is correct, for $\sum_kz_k=1$, it is because for any of the k-dimensional vector, there is only one binary component to be 1 (all others are zero), so the sum of all binary component is 1?

Comment: Hi Michael, have some new thoughts, and just to confirm my understanding is correct, for $\sum_kz_k=1$, it is because for any specific dimension of the k-dimensional vector, there is only one specific dimension to be 1 (all others are zero), so the sum of all values of dimensions is 1?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: @lmo, thanks for the confirmation, could you help to add a reply, I will mark it as answer to benefit other people.

Comment: just fyi it's usually called the [one-hot representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-hot)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For each $x_i$ in the sample $(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ one can create an binary (and unobserved) vector $\mathbf{z}_i=(z_{i1},\ldots,z_{iK})$ made of components in $\{0,1\}$ such that one and only one of the $z_{ij}$'s is equal to one, e.g., $\mathbf{z}_i=(0,\ldots,0,1,0,\ldots,0)$, and all others are equal to zero. The corresponding $j$ is called the component of $x_i$. Conditional on $\mathbf{z}_i$, $x_i$ is distributed as a normal variate $$\mathcal{N}\left(\sum_{j=1}^K z_{ij}\mu_j,\sum_{j=1}^K z_{ij}\Sigma_j\right)$$Marginally, the vector $\mathbf{z}_i$ is distributed as a Multinomial $\mathcal{M}_K(1;\pi_1,\ldots,\pi_k)$ variate.

Comment: Thanks Xi'an, vote up, what means $\mu_j$ and $\sum_j$ in your formula?

Comment: This is the same notation as in formula (9.7).